# Operators on date/time fields

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

Is the `+` and `-` operator defined in standard sql on date/time types, for example Time, Duration, Date, Datetime, Timestamp. Here is an example from MySQL:

```
select 
date '1983-09-05', time '01:02:03', timestamp '2014-01-01 01:02:03',
date '1983-09-05' + time '01:02:03', timestamp '1983-09-05 01:02:03' + time '01:02:03'
```

It seems the last three results just give gibberish (in terms of actually giving a meaningful result). Is there a standard in how time-types are supposed to add and subtract or it's undefined behavior and it's suggested to use functions for this kind of stuff?

Comment: To my knowledge the SQL standard only defines the operations `timestamp +/- interval`  and `timestamp - timestamp` but not e.g. `date + time` or `timestamp + time`. Postgres for example supports `date + time` which simply yields a `timestamp`, but `timestamp + time` isn't supported (which doesn't make sense anyway). But `timestamp + interval` obviously is. As MySQL's "time" type is essentially an `interval` in disguise (as it allows more than 24 hours) maybe that's why it accepts the syntax

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. I think `timestamp + time` would be ok though, no? What about if it's 2pm on Friday and you want to know what time it will be 3 hours from now? I'm writing it informally but that would translate to timestamp + time/duration, right?

Comment: "3 hours from now" is an `interval`, so you need `timestamp + interval`. As I already wrote: MySQL's "time" data type isn't really a `time` type as defined by the SQL standard which represents "the time of the day", e.g. "8 o'clock in the morning" or "half past midnight". MySQL's "time" type is closer to what is defined as `interval hours to minute` in the SQL standard.

Comment: I wonder why it would be useful to know or ponder upon this esoteric stuff

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - MySQL "accepts the syntax" but for both cases in the question just converts the operands to integers by ignoring non digits and adds them https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7279ef8a88e1bb39537f32cfe79c3fd9

Comment: @MartinSmith: I know MySQL accepts it. But it makes no sense - at least not to me and (apparently not do David542 either). Postgres does the right thing though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=89cdecf181dde0c792f8aae89ef65142 (I have to admit that I **am** surprised that `timestamp + time` actually works)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It doesn't really "actually work" It looks like `+` is probably just defined for numbers in MySQL - so you get an implicit cast to integer. So `timestamp` + `time` doesn't do anything useful - this is more apparent when adding `23:59:59` on both sides https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a9986da3cf8fe8050486f4536975ba7

Comment: @MartinSmith: I was referring to the fact that `timestamp + time` works in Postgres - it's undocumented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't produce gibberish.  It just gets confused.  The problem is that MySQL is trying to figure out what you mean:

- Is `+` really for numeric addition or for date/times?
- Is the constant really a string, date/time, or number?

MySQL makes choices for these that are (perhaps) counterintuitive.  For instance, a date/time values such as `'2014-01-01 01:02:03'` is converted to a number that looks like `20140101010203`.  This conversion happens implicitly under some circumstances.

Let me illustrate this just with the dates.  You might think these are equivalent:

```
select '2021-01-01' + 40,
       date '2021-01-01' + 40,
       '2021-01-01' + interval 40 day
```

And the results are:

```
2061    20210141    2021-02-10
```

What is happening?  In the first, `+` is treated a number addition.  the first argument is converted to a number -- that is leading digits up to the first non-digit.

In the second, `+` is treated a number addition as well.  The date is converted to a number and it looks like 20,210,101 -- that is YYYYMMDD as an *integer*.

Finally, the third tells MySQL to do what you intend -- add 40 days.

This has *nothing* to do with standard SQL, which clearly defines adding and subtracting intervals and the difference of timestamps.  These are just the rules that MySQL uses for disambiguating `+` and `-` and for converting date/times to numbers.

Comment: thanks, as always, for this. One question: `standard SQL, which clearly defines adding and subtracting intervals and the difference of timestamps` -- does it mention "how" that needs to be done -- for example with the usage of an operator or a function? Or it just says that it needs to be done, and it's up to the vendor to decide how?

Comment: @David542 . . . Yes.  The standard specifies `+`/`-` as supported operators for those operations.